# jQuery – waiting for setTimeout before next run of .each()

Tags: jquery

I hope you can give me a quick fix for something I'm struggling with. I have found the odd person with a similar problem but can't get my head around something that clearly can't be that difficult!

I'm looking for the below code to wait until the `setTimeout` has finished before it loops to the next `.each()`

```
$('.someClass').each(function() {
    var thisWindow = $(this);
    var someDelay = someOtherVariable
    setTimeout(function(){
        thisWindow.removeClass('hidden');
        console.log($(this));
    },someDelay);  
});
```

I'm assuming some sort of queue will help, but I am definitely not a jQuery expert! The answers I've seen seem to deal with animation, which this isn't, so I apologise if I've missed something obvious in my previous searches. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turned out, I didn't need to actually block the `.each()` loop for my particular use. I just kept a track of 'totalDelaySoFar' and added that to the delay for each item, such that they finished running at the right times.

I ended up with:

```
var totalDelay = 0;
$('.someClass').each(function() {
    var thisWindow = $(this);
    var someDelay = totalDelay + someOtherVariable;
    totalDelay += someDelay;
    setTimeout(function(){
        thisWindow.removeClass('hidden');
        console.log($(this));
    },someDelay);  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

its very simple.

you need to give a counter with that function. so:

```
$('.someClass').each(function(i) {
    var thisWindow = $(this);
    var someDelay = 500;
    setTimeout(function(){
        thisWindow.removeClass('hidden');
        console.log($(this));
     },i * someDelay);  
});
```

with that i and that small calculation at the end every element gets 500ms more delay.

so for the first walkthrough:

0 * 500 = 0

second:

1*500 = 500

third:

2*500 = 1000

and so on.

see working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkbjLbx3/1/) too:

greetings timotheus!

Comment: This works really well, much better than my suggestion

Comment: That'd be great, except the duration of the delay changes each time. I think I worked it out just after I posted the question, I haven't had a chance to try it out since though. I think I'll just keep track of the total delay and add that to the necessary delay for each element. Should work for the odd, purposefully awful user experience that I need. I shall report back!

Answer (score 0):

`each` loop is not going to wait for setTimeout to move onto the next item, as it's meant for non-blocking execution of several "threads" (although JS is not really multi-threaded).

Each will set separate, parallel timers for each element on your list before the first `setTimeout` starts firing. The purpose of `setTimeout` is to let the code that calls it proceed without interruption and execute the first parameter when timeout occurs.

If you want to advance to the next element when the timeout finished, you have to do that manually, not using `$.each()`. That way, you control the rate at which execution moves to the next matched item.

You can iterate over every element on the matched set (using a `for... in` loop) and using sleep(xxxx); However, be aware that sleep will freeze execution until the delay has ended, so it might not be what you want, from a user-experience perspective.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use jquery `delay()` method:

```
$.each($('.foo'), function(i, item) {
    $(item).delay(1000 * i).fadeIn();
});
```

This will fade in next .foo element each second.

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/m0fxm2Lu/